# How to calculate last four year date based on date string

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario in which I need to calculate last four year date based on current date provided from backend (REST API). And on calculating I need to store it in an array.

Example : current date "12-06-2017", how do I calculate last four year date based on current year.

Task : As I need to show the reports of current year and last four years report. And need to cascade that array of current and last four years into select box.

Comment: So, what would your array look like? [2017, 2016, 2015, 2014]?

Comment: Yeah first it will be great if u can achieve this. Will be helpful

Comment: And your input is "12-06-2017", as string?

Comment: Right from a rest API I will get a key with a string value as "12-06-2017"

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be that hard:

```
var input = "12-06-2017";
var year = parseInt(input.split("-")[2])

var years = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   years.push(year - i);
}

var results = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
   results.push(years[i] + "-" + years[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: But suppose on basis of date that I received from rest API json , if I need to show the select option values as 2016-2017 then 2015-2016 then 2014-2015 . How to achieve this

Comment: You need to define properly what your array looks like. Is it array of numbers? Array of strings? What values does it contain?

Comment: On basis of the date I need to show the select box options as 2016-2017 , 2015-2016, 2014-2015 so that the user get to know that he / she is seeing the report of that particular year based on selection . Hope you got my view. And thank you for your quick response

Comment: Thanks for your help , but is there any better way of doing it or can u create a function of it in which we can pass a parameter as a year and it will return me an array in form of results array that you created . Thanks once again

Comment: Just wrap it in a function, and make input to be the argument.

Comment: Can we perform the same thing using moment js library?